# setting a var and return new value at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run in to a problem whan i do somthing like this

```
var abc = false;
function doSomthing(){
abc = true;
return abc;
}
```

and it returns false, but if i run the function twice (in console), the second time returns true.

Thanks

the orignal function

```
var session_id_resualt = false;

function islogdin() {
    if (localStorage.email == undefined) {
        localStorage.email = "";
    }

    if (localStorage.session_id == undefined) {
        localStorage.session_id = "";
    }

    $.post(server + "loginCheck.php", {
        loginCheck: "",
        cookie: readCookie("h"),
        session_id: localStorage.session_id,
        email: localStorage.email
    },

    function (json) {
        json = $.parseJSON(json);
        if (json.logdin) {
            if (json.logdin == "1") {
                //var s_id = json.session_id;
                session_id_resualt = json.session_id;
                //return s_id;          
            } else {
                session_id_resualt = false;
                //  return false;
            }

        } else {
            session_id_resualt = false;
            //  return false;
        }
    });
    return session_id_resualt;

}
```

Comment: When are you calling the function?

Comment: Check your point of call.

Comment: Why do you need to return `abc` if it's available outside the scope of `doSomething` anyway?

Comment: I am calling the function on load
the function is in a js file that i include in the page that i am call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.post` is asynchronous. You'll need to wait for the result. However, since `$.post` doens't provide a simple way to change the `$.ajax` settings you'll have to use `$.ajax` instead with `async: false`:

```
var data = {
    loginCheck: "",
    cookie: readCookie("h"),
    session_id: localStorage.session_id,
    email: localStorage.email
};

var url = server + "loginCheck.php";

var callback = function (json) {
    /* ... */
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    async: false, /* importan! */
    data: data,
    success: callback,
});
```

#### References:

- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)